# Injective function from Integers to Naturals?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can there be an injective (one-to-one) function from all Integers to all Naturals? Or from all Rationals to all Integers?
Intuition would imply that this is impossible, simply because Naturals also belong to Integers, meaning there are "more numbers" in Integers than in Naturals. I would imagine this argument valid with finite groups, but what about an infinite group that conatins another infinite group?

Thank you

Comment: See [Countable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) : **Proposition**: The (set of) integers $\mathbb Z$ is countable and the (set of) rational numbers $\mathbb Q$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc there is such a function. Because $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb N$ are equinumerous, so there exists a bijection between them. They are both countable, so is $\Bbb Q$, the set of all rationals. So there is also a bijective function between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb N$, so especially an injective one.

e.g. Take $f: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb N$ given by:
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} 2z & z\ge 0 \\ -(2z+1) & z<0 \end{cases}$$

what is an injective function from the integers to the naturals…

Comment: Thank you, How would you describe such a function between the rationals and naturals?

Comment: Check literature for  Cantor's first diagonal argument…